# Intellij not respecting some options in build.sbt

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have an autogenerated SBT project by intellij, in which I am want to add something to `java.library.path`. I add the following line to the build.sbt:

`javaOptions += s"-Djava.library.path=blahblah"`

Inside my simple scala code, I print the path:

```
object JniExampleScala {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"))
    }
}
```

When running from command line (`sbt compile` and  `sbt run`), it prints the path `blahblah`, but when running inside intellij, it prints the default path. 
Why intellij does not read build.sbt?

Comment: IntelliJ only reads the dependencies and project layout from build.sbt. You have to separately configure your Run Configurations.

Comment: @AkosKrivachy But why is this the case? Can we force to get all properties from sbt file?

Comment: Well look, when you import the `build.sbt` do you have any existing Run Configurations? I usually don't and have to create them for myself. So if you create it yourself then you are no longer using SBT to run your application. They are two separate run environments and need the VM options configured. If you would like to submit a feature request then head over to the IntelliJ website.

Answer (score 1):

At my expirience IDEA have very limited support of sbt projects. That was main reason for me to use maven instead (with it's horrible pom xml). While we use sbt our usage of idea was limited by editor features (project was complicated enough to be uncompilable from idea). We may compile assembly and run aps with sbt console utility only.

Sbt is nice modern tool. But support in IDEs is still bad

Comment: in 2017 it is not actual. Idea can import most sbt projects properly